# $n(n+1- \phi(n)) = (n+2021)(n+2022 - \phi(n+2021))$

Tags: number-theory, totient-function

VMO 2021:

Find all integers $n \geq 2$ such that: $n(n+1- \phi(n)) = (n+2021)(n+2022 - \phi(n+2021))$

I think $n$ does not exsist.

+, If $\gcd(n,2021)=1 \Rightarrow \gcd(n+2021,n)=1$

then $(n+2021) \mid (n+1- \phi(n))$

What should I do next?

Comment: This is taken from [Question 4 part b)](https://www.mathvn.com/2020/12/e-thi-hoc-sinh-gioi-toan-quoc-gia-vmo.html) of the VMO 2021.

Comment: What made you think it doesn't exit?

Comment: A brute force search would be a good start. How far have you checked ? If no solution upto a high limit exists , then you still can try to prove that none exists.

Comment: Up to $10^7$ there is no solution

Comment: Discussion is going on in this posting of AOPS: https://artofproblemsolving.com/community/u350745h2389832p19615716

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are some brute force approach is involved in my solution. Given that this is an Olympiad question, there should be a way to avoid the brute force approach. The main idea of the solution comes from the comment https://artofproblemsolving.com/community/c6h2389832p19615716 by Rickyminer and a solution to a similar problem https://artofproblemsolving.com/community/c6h347925p1865700 by Pathological in AOPS.

**Case 1: $\gcd(n,2021)=1$**

We proceed as Minh Hien did. Since $\gcd(n,n+2021)=1$, the equation
$$
n(n+1- \phi(n)) = (n+2021)(n+2022 - \phi(n+2021)) \ \ (1)
$$
gives $n+2021 | n+1-\phi(n)$. This is a contradiction.

**Case 2: $\gcd(n,2021)=43$**

We write $n=43k$. We have $\gcd(k,47)=1$, the equation (1) becomes
$$
k(43k+1-\phi(43k))=(k+47)(43k+2022-\phi(43(k+47)).
$$
Since $\gcd(k,k+47)=1$, there is a positive integer $t<43$ such that
$$
43k+1-\phi(43k)=t(k+47), 
$$
$$
43k+2022-\phi(43(k+47))=tk.
$$
By subtracting the second from the first, we have
$$
\phi(43(k+47))-\phi(43k)=47(t+43).
$$
Since $42$ divides the LHS, we have $t=41$. This gives
$$
\phi(43k)=2k-1926
$$
$$
\phi(43(k+47))=2k+2022.
$$
Let $k+47=43^e(k+47)_{43}$ where $\gcd((k+47)_{43},43)=1$. Let $k=43^fk_{43}$ where $\gcd(k_{43},43)=1$.
We obtain
$$
43^{e-1}\phi((k+47)_{43})-43^{f-1}\phi(k_{43})=47\cdot 2.  \ \ (2)
$$
One of the two terms on the LHS must be $2$ mod $4$. If the first term is $2$ mod $4$, then $(k+47)_{43}$ is $p^a$, $2p^a$, or $4$ for odd prime $p$.
For these numbers $\phi((k+47)_{43})/(k+47)_{43}$ is usually large. To be precise, we have the inequality
$$
\frac{\phi(43(k+47))}{43(k+47)} = \frac{2k+2022}{43(k+47)} \geq \left(1-\frac1{43}\right) \cdot \frac13.
$$
The inequality gives $k\leq 113$. We leave this to brute force check.

If the second term of (2) is $2$ mod $4$,
$$
\frac{\phi(43k)}{43k}=\frac{2k-1926}{43k} \geq \left(1-\frac1{43}\right)\frac13
$$
does not have a solution.

**Case 3: $\gcd(n,2021)=47$**

We proceed similarly as in Case 2. The equation (1) becomes
$$
k(47k+1-\phi(47k))=(k+43)(47k+2022-\phi(47(k+43)).
$$
Write $n=47k$, $gcd(k,43)=1$. We obtain
$$
\phi(47k)=2k-1934,
$$
$$
\phi(47(k+43))=2k+2022, 
$$
and
$$
47^{e-1}\phi((k+43)_{47})-47^{f-1}\phi(k_{47})=43\cdot 2. \ \ (3)
$$
If the first term is $2$ mod $4$, then $(k+43)_{47}$ is $p^a$, $2p^a$, or $4$ for odd prime $p$. Then we have
$$
\frac{\phi(47(k+43))}{47(k+43)}=\frac{2k+2022}{47(k+43)} \geq \left(1-\frac1{47}\right)\cdot \frac13. 
$$
The last inequality gives $k\leq 102$. We leave this to a brute force check.

If the second term of (3) is $2$ mod $4$, then we have no solution similarly as in Case 2.

**Case 4: $\gcd(n,2021)=2021$**

We write $n=2021k$.
The equation (1) becomes
$$
k(2021k+1-\phi(2021k))=(k+1)(2021k+2022-\phi(2021(k+1)).
$$
Proceeding as in Case 2, we have
$$
\phi(2021k)=178k-1842,
$$
$$
\phi(2021(k+1))=178k+2022,
$$
and
$$
43^{e_1-1}47^{e_2-1}\phi((k+1)_{43,47}) - 43^{f_1-1}47^{f_2-1}\phi(k_{43,47})=2. \ \ (4)
$$
If the first term is $2$ mod $4$, we have $(k+1)_{43,47}$ is $p^a$, $2p^a$, or $4$ for odd prime $p$. Then
$$
\frac{\phi(2021(k+1))}{2021(k+1)}=\frac{178k+2022}{2021(k+1)} \geq \left(1-\frac1{43}\right)\left(1-\frac1{47}\right)\frac13.
$$
The last equality gives $k\leq 2$. But, this does not satisfy the equality above.

**Brute force cases**

The cases with brute force checking left are covered with a Python code that there are no solutions.

Comment: (+1) Considering this is an Olympiad question brute forcing 113 cases would be the last thing to expect so I’m not sure why OP accepted this.

Comment: @TheSimpliFire For the case 2, $k\leq 113$, I proved there is no solution without having to check all $k\leq 113$. So, I would think that the other brute forcing cases can be handled the same way. But, I stopped trying it. Maybe someone else should do them and add another answer. Then OP can accept the other answer.